# Insert data listing columns with partitioning field in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

First of all let's setup a test environment:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS source_table (
  `col1` TIMESTAMP,
  `col2` STRING
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dest_table (
  `col1` TIMESTAMP,
  `col2` STRING,
  `col3` STRING
)
PARTITIONED BY (day STRING)
STORED AS AVRO;

INSERT INTO TABLE source_table VALUES ('2018-03-21 17:08:04.401', 'test1'), ('2018-03-22 12:02:04.222', 'test2'), ('2018-03-22 07:21:04.111', 'test3');
```

How could I list the column names during insertion and put the partition value dynamically? The following command doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE dest_table(col1, col2) PARTITION(day) SELECT col1, col2, date_format(col1, 'yyyy-MM-dd') FROM source_table;
```

By the way, without listing the columns of `dest_table` inside the `INSERT INTO` command, having two tables with the same columns number, everything works fine. What if my `dest_table` has more fields than the `source_table`?

Thank you for helping me.

**P.S.**

Ok, if I hardcode `NULL` this works. I leave the question opened because there might be better ways to achieve that.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE dest_table PARTITION(day) SELECT col1, col2, NULL, date_format(col1, 'yyyy-MM-dd') FROM source_table;
```

Anyway, this method is strictly bounded with columns order? In a real-life scenario, how could I handle lots of columns specifying a mapping, to avoid mistakes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for inserting into a partitioned table when you want to list the specific columns is shown below. You don't need to put null on col3 since Hive will put a default value NULL since it is not in the column list during insert.

```
  INSERT INTO TABLE dest_table PARTITION (day)(col1, col2, day)
  SELECT col1, col2, date_format(col1, 'yyyy-MM-dd') FROM source_table;

Result:
col1                    col2    col3    day
2018-03-22 12:02:04.222 test2   NULL    2018-03-22
2018-03-22 07:21:04.111 test3   NULL    2018-03-22
2018-03-21 17:08:04.401 test1   NULL    2018-03-21
```